# Accessing Visual Studio 2010 project properties in Visual Basic macro

Tags: vb.net, properties, macros, project, lint

My company does a lot of work with `LINT`, so to make our lives easier, we wrote a few Macros into Visual Studio that allowed us to easily `compile LINT` files. However, we came across a problem. Because the format of **Visual Studio 2010** solution files changed, our Macros no longer worked, so my company put me in charge of updating them.
My issue comes in here. I am trying to access the preprocessor definitions of the currently selected **VS project inside the macro**, but the names used in the Project Properties page don't appear in the code. I have been searching through the internet trying to find a way of accessing this information in my code, but all the answers I have found point me in the wrong direction.
The classes I thought I was supposed to working with are the `DTE.Project and DTE.Configuration classes.`
Any ideas as to how I acess the information I'm looking for inside the code?

EDIT: I know (thanks to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984571(v=vs.71).aspx) that **there is no direct programmatic access to the properties through the ProjectProperties interface**, but that doesn't make it impossible.

EDIT: The object properties of the Project and Configuration class do not match the properties shown in the Project Properties UI. The properties I am searching for may exist *under* one of these properties or may exist in a different class

Comment: You're updating the macros for VS2010? Given that macro support is dropped in VS2012, would it not be more prudent to re-write the functionality entirely at this point? Otherwise, you'll just be doing another re-write when you next upgrade.

Comment: It isn't the macro that has stopped working for us. It's the translation from VS solution to LINT file. The idea was that we create a macro that _manually_ translates to LINT and then the macro we've already written can continue to do its work

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read VS2010 for a moment. That is a very good point. I will have to discuss this with my higher powers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to my superiors, we decided to go in the direction of a VS Add-in, as Damien_The_Unbeliever was correct. However, I quickly came across the same problem in C# as I had in VB.
It was solved by a stupid amount of meta-programming. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/23763118-c34f-45fc-97aa-5fe5c4ad4d5c/
That was the only useful link I found in two days of searching, for anyone else who comes across this issue.

I hope that explains it :)